# How to have SWIG Generate PyCapsules Instead of PyObjects in Python 3?

Tags: python, c, swig

I am dealing with updating the following snippet of C Extension code to compile into a Python3.4-compatible module via Swig 3.0.5 (`swig -python -modern -py3 -o swig_module.c swig_module.i`):

```
static PyObject *SomeFunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    struct MyStruct *S;
    PyObject *obj = NULL;
    if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"O:some_func",&obj))
    {
       // S = (struct MyStruct *)PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(obj); // PY2
       // Python 3 Version discussed below           
    }
}
```

The only element of `args` read into `SomeFunc` is a C Object of type `SwigPyObject`.  In Python 2 it is straightforward to use `PyCObject_AsVoidPtr` to access the "raw C pointer" which is stored in memory as follows:

`|32 Bytes for PyObject|raw C pointer|...`

The Python3 analogue to `PyCObject_AsVoidPtr` appears to be `PyCapsule_GetPointer`.  However `PyCapsule_GetPointer` requires a `PyCapsule` as an argument in order to return the raw C pointer, and try as I might, Swig invariably points `&obj` to a `PyObject` which `PyCapsule_GetPointer` rejects, so I cannot extract the raw C pointer.

`PyCapsule` is an opaque structure in Python 3, but experiments in a debugger demonstrate that the memory structure outlined above has not changed, so manually casting the incoming `PyObject` as a `PyCapsule` successfully retrieves the pointer, i.e.:

```
S = (struct MyStruct *)((PyCapsule *)obj)->pointer;
```

Works in a PY3 compile, and there is much rejoicing.  However this requires manually adding the opaque-by-design `PyCapsule` definition to my source, which strikes me as very dangerous thing to be doing (since it relies on a definition of `PyCapsule` that might change, etc).

So how am I supposed to "get" Swig to point `&obj` to a `PyCapsule` in a way that will allow me to use `...GetPointer` without resorting to horrid tricks (somehow having `SwigPyObject` be a type of `SwigPyCapsule`, assuming the latter even exists)?  I'm brand new to Swig and Python C extensions, so please excuse any ignorant statements above.